# problem with textField.htmlText and apostrophe (')

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Apostrophe is shown in `textField.htmlText` as `&apos` (which is not a valid html encoding of apostrophe), intead of `&#39`.
How can i change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ' you forgot the ";" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the escape character sequence for the apostrophe ( \' ), newline ( \n ), return ( \r ), and many other characters in the AS3 using an htmlText TextField.

Here is the related article: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=textcontrols_04.html